# Problem with MVC3 updgrade. Update to MVC3 from MVC2 Web App Solution, possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I tried upgrading the solution to MVC3 in VS2010 by using an upgrader [tool](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/07/28/migrating-asp-net-mvc-2-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx)

I don't know what it does exactly but it didn't work. My "System.Web.Mvc" is not being recognized in my project.

Is there anything specific I should be doing with my web.config? I don't quite understand the underlying details about all the places I should be referencing dll's or what "binding" even means and when I should use it inside the web.config

**So I have to ask, what is the best method for upgrading to MVC3 and what have you done that works?**

Thanks a bunch friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the reference? What happens if you delete the reference from the project and add it back from the file location where you installed MVC3?

Comment: not sure where MVC3 is installed, I used an executable it did it by itself.

Comment: @Ehsan Do a search for it... System.web.Mvc.dll or look in c:\program files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3